# Lomonsov gravity vs liberal-relativistic gravity

Tags: theoretical-physics

Just wonder if there was ever any response to Mikhail Lomonsov's theory that Gravity is pressure differences in the aether. This overcomes self interaction and other problems in liberal gravity.

Comment: What is liberal-relativistic gravity? A link or reference would help too, this is not a common term. And Lomonosov's was a vague speculation, more detailed ideas along the same lines were proposed earlier by Huygens and Fatio, see [Wikipedia's Mechanical explanations of gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_explanations_of_gravitation#Other_historical_speculations).

Comment: One might surmise that Michaelson & Morley put an end to this particular conjecture.

Comment: What is liberal gravity?  And as far as I understand it, Lomonsov never provided a complete description of how the aether interacts with matter, so your speculation appears to be quite unfounded. Please provide sources for your claims, otherwise I am tempted to downvote this question.